# mapping bean information while creating SessionFactory object from HibernateUtils

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I have created a sessionFactory object from HibernateUtils as below

```
configuration.setProperty("connection.driver_class",prop.getProperty("driverClassName"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",prop.getProperty("url"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", prop.getProperty("username"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", prop.getProperty("password"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", prop.getProperty("dialect"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", prop.getProperty("schema"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        configuration.setProperty("packagesToScan", "daoBean");
```

I have a database where Test database and stock table is already created in this.
Now I am mapping a model object to insert the information.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyongdb", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;
    private StockDetail stockDetail;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName, StockDetail stockDetail) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.stockDetail = stockDetail;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getStockId() {
        return this.stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getStockCode() {
        return this.stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getStockName() {
        return this.stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public StockDetail getStockDetail() {
        return this.stockDetail;
    }

    public void setStockDetail(StockDetail stockDetail) {
        this.stockDetail = stockDetail;
    }

}
```

please suggest to map the stock object to insert data.

Answer (score 0):

I got your pain point.

please add this line

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Stock.class);
```

I think this will solve your problem.